# Falling through switch statement (works sometimes?)

Tags: c#, switch-statement, fall-through

I have a switch statement such as the one below:

```
switch (condition)
{
    case 0:
    case 1:
        // Do Something
        break;
    case 2:
        // Do Something
    case 3:
        // Do Something
        break;
}
```

I get a compile error telling me that `Control cannot fall through from one case label ('case 2:') to another`

Well... Yes you can.  Because you are doing it from `case 0:` through to `case 1:`.

And in fact if I remove my `case 2:` and it's associated task, the code compiles and will fall through from `case 0:` into `case1:`.

So what is happening here and how can I get my case statements to fall through AND execute some intermediate code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a difference between stacking labels and fall-through.

C# supports the former:

```
case 0:
case 1:
    break;
```

but not fall-through:

```
case 2:
    // Do Something
case 3:
    // Do Something
    break;
```

If you want fall-through, you need to be explicit:

```
case 2:
    // Do Something
    goto case 3;
case 3:
    // Do Something
    break;
```

The reasoning is apparent, implicit fall-through can lead to unclean code, especially if you have more than one or two lines, and it isn't clear how the control flows anymore. By forcing the explicit fall-through, you can easily follow the flow.

Reference: [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Also note that it's common to just forget to add the `break` which could lead to unintentional falling through.

Comment: Accepted this answer for being the most complete and for being the first to include information on `goto case`, which is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for providing the proper goto syntax!

Answer (score 3):

Quoting MSDN:

"C# does not support an implicit fall through from one case label to another. The one exception is if a case statement has no code."

basically it is not legal to put statements inside the case and not include a break.

```
case 1:
case 2:
//do stuff
break;
```

is legal

but:

```
case 1:
//do stuff without a break
case 2:
//do stuff
break;
```

is not.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You are not falling from `case 0` to `case 1` since they share the same code block. This is the same as writing `case 1` before `case 0`.

Answer (score 1):

In C#, you cannot fall through a label to another implicitly except if there is no specific code for the first label.
You can have

```
case 1:
case 2:
    // Do Something
break;
```

but not

```
case 1:
    // Do Something
case 2:
    // Do Something
break;
```

See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for a more in-depth explanation.

If you wish to fall through explicitly, you can by using the [goto](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) instruction. It is also one of the rare case where using goto isn't a bad practice.

```
case 1:
    // Do Something
    goto case 2;
case 2:
    // Do Something
break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Code can "fall through" in C# only when there is no code between the case statements. The code example infers there is code between case 2 and case 3.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** allowed

```
switch (condition)
{
    case 0:
        // Do Something
    case 1:
        // Do Something
        break;
}
```

This is allowed

```
    switch (condition)
    {
        case 0:
        case 1:
            // Do Something
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're doing something in case 2 and then trying to fall through, and that's not supported. You're going from 0 to 1 without any additionaly activity.