# C# goto from using statement

Tags: c#, using, goto

Do

```
using and goto
```

statements dispose objects if the code looks similar to this?

```
public T MyMethod(){
     using(stream){
         //do some work here
         if(completed){
             //do some work
             goto next;
         }
         return something;
     }
   next:
     //do another work here...
     //is stream disposed?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will be disposed. There's a similar question with an answer here: [GOTO inside using block, will the object get disposed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584249/goto-inside-using-block-will-the-object-get-disposed)

By the way, I personally discourage the use of `goto`. You can achieve the same behaviour with `if` statements.

Comment: +1. I overlooked this question was already asked. I'll mark this as an answer.